# Python - Best way to parse specific, standardized information in PDF documents?

Tags: python, pdf, split, text-parsing

I am trying to parse these PDF "Arms Sale Notification" letters, found here: 
http://www.dsca.mil/pressreleases/36-b/36b_index.htm

Here is a specific PDF document example, of a proposed arms sale to Oman:
http://www.dsca.mil/pressreleases/36-b/2013/Oman13-07.pdf

Since I have 600 of these documents, the information I want to extract in the example include the country name (Oman), the list of articles to be sold ("AN/AAQ-24(V) Large Aircraft Infrared Countermeasures (LAIRCM) Systems", the cost of the sale ("$100 million") and the primary contractor ("Northrop Grumman Corporation of Rolling Meadows, Illinois").

What sort of regular expressions or split() function specifications could I use to isolate these pieces of information from a document like this?

Comment: Have you checked how differently those in-text informations (cost and contractor) are presented in all those documents. It might require an actual AI...

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the converted text first to determine the regular expression.  PDFs can be quirky about text conversion.  I would recommend ReportLabs over pyPDF as the PDF parsing library of choice.